# Append new data to existing feature class using Load Data in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, csv, feature-class, append, error-001156

I am trying to append new rows of data for a feature class that shares the exact same fields (column headers and types) but wasn't able to using **Load Data** in ArcGIS Pro. In ArcMap, you could easily hit reload table cache and the table will update by calling the CSV that it uses to plot the feature class. But it seems very difficult to do it in ArcGIS Pro.

When using "Load Data" function, I tried 2 options:

1. *Input schema must match target schema* - the input table has the exact same header with new data to be appended. It kicked **Error 000466**.
2. *Use the Field Map to reconcile schema differences* - Same input table, but I also double checked in the Field Map section to make sure the properties of each output field is the same as what is in the feature class now. This step gave the **Error 001156**.

I might not be exactly sure how to use this tool.

Comment: FYI I am using ArcGIS Pro 2.6.1

Comment: CSV files are known to be problematic, you might get better results if you import into a personal geodatabase table using Microsoft Access. There's a good chance that the CSV contains at least one type error which can be caused by a string in a numeric field or by having an erroneous comma in a text field causing the following columns to jump by one. If you don't have Microsoft Access you can validate and convert the CSV using arcpy if you have any knowledge of python and arcpy.

Comment: I think you should focus your question on one of the two ways that you've tried to solve this.  You can also ask about the other way in a separate question.  That way you'll be able to provide a more detailed description of precisely what you tried.